# Display detail under single item in angular

Tags: angular, css, bootstrap-4

I am using angular 7 and bootstrap 4 for this project. I want to get detail exact under the selected item. Here is the screenshot currently I am on. 
[image]

and here is what I want to achieve.

[image]

Currently I am getting team detail at the bottom of the page as you can see in the first picture, however, I want the team detail exactly below the selected card.

Here is my code:

TeamListComponent

```
export class TeamListComponent implements OnInit {

  teams: any;

  constructor(private ts: TeamsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ts.getTeams().subscribe(data=> {
      this.teams = data.teams;
    })
  }
}
```

TeamListTemplate; Note: The router-outlet takes to the team detail component.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <app-team *ngFor="let team of teams" [team]=team></app-team>
  </div>
<div class="row">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</div>
```

single team component

```
export class TeamComponent{
      @Input() team: any;
}
```

team template: Note: I am using bootstrap cards to display team

```
<div class="card border-dark " style="width: 300px; height: 450px; margin: 10px;" [routerLink]="team.id"
     routerLinkActive="active">
  <img class="card-img-top embed-responsive" src="{{team.crestUrl}}" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{team.name}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{team.address}}</p>
    <a href="{{team.website}}" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg btn-block" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please suggest me the solution if you need more detail, please let me know. TIA

Comment: I think I understand your question now; I'm going to delete my answer since it hasn't answered your question

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <app-team *ngFor="let team of teams" [team]=team></app-team>
    <div><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
  </div>
</div>


Just place your router-outlet inside the same row and make some the adjustment according your need. Hope it will help
```

Comment: I will revert back when i know

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is to place your `<team-detail></team-detail>` inside the `<team></team>` element. When user clicks it display the `<team-detail></team-detail>`, this way it will be displayed below that component.

Another way is to use `<ng-content></ng-content>` inside `<team></team>`. And pass `<team-detail></team-detail>` as follows,

`<team>
  <team-detail></team-detail>
</team>`

Comment: Hi emkay, in the first solution, if I put team-detail component in a team, as team component it a *ngFor in team-list, it will loop through and will render the same team-detail for all teams. and the second solution I could not get it properly. Thanks

Comment: You are passing team object the <team> component right, now inside the template of <team> component, when you will place the team detail, it should get the data as present in the team object which I suppose is different for all <team> component. Why will it be same team-detail for all teams?